# jquery Equal height ajax load content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using following code for equal height of div's and li's.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc)

It is working find on load and resize. But when div's load by ajax then it will not work. for ajax load i use

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
 equalheight('.list-item');
});
```

And

```
$("#step_2").on("change", "#subcategory_id", function(){
    equalheight('.list-item');
});
```

But not working. Any idea or help please?

Comment: Please tell me what error you get..

Comment: Not any error in console. But when div's load by ajax they are not getting height. When i alert on ajax load given undefined.

Comment: I think you need use $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
}); or use $.ajax with url and in success function put 'equalheight('.list-item');'

Comment: i used it but no success...

Comment: <script>
equalheight = function(container){


}

$(window).load(function(){
  equalheight('.p-row .p-item-li .p-item');
});


$(window).resize(function(){
  equalheight('.p-row .p-item-li .p-item');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ 
 equalheight('.p-row .p-item-li .p-item');
});

</script>

Comment: Please show your html code